# Django field lookups day not work

Tags: python, django

The model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    stop_date = models.DateTimeField()
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

when i use field lookups `day` , the result is not my expect:

```
a_list = A.objects.filter(stop_date__day=10)
```

the a_list is a empty queryset. But the database has some records which the `day` of `stop_date` is 10.

In settings.py,

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Is there something wrong with the time zone setting?

Expect your help.

Comment: And how are you confirming there are entries in the DB with a day of 10?

Comment: yeah, I confirmed it and there it is. I inserted into the table befor i test it.@JonClements

Comment: Okay... but how are you checking it outside django it's there *now*... Have you run a select query on the table for instance and you're getting results?

Comment: What do you get if you ask for `A.objects.values('stop_date__day')`?

Comment: I run the select query and get the results@JonClements

Comment: Can this work? It shows error `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'day' into field. Join on 'stop_date' not permitted.`@JonKiparsky

Comment: update your database timezone tables and try it will work